# wp_nav_menu in ul instead of div wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using latest wordpress theme but when I am implementing navigation with `wp_nav_menu()` then its bind my class in 'div', but I need my class in 'ul' instead of 'div' here is my code

```
<?php 
    wp_nav_menu(array( 
        'menu' => 'primary', 
        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right', 
        'menu_id' => '', 
        'container' => false, 
        'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 
        'show_home' => '1')
    ); 
?>
```

and result is coming

```
<div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <ul>
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/incubation/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/incubation/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But I need my classes comes in '`ul`' instead of '`div`' and '`div`' tag totally will be removed from my code. something like this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/incubation/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/incubation/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
'items_wrap'      => '<div id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</div>',
'echo' => '0',
'container' => '',
```

Comment: this code remove my html section because of 'echo' => '0'

Comment: but have you got div instead of ul ?

Comment: thnx @vrajesh I got solution :)

Comment: if my answer is right please tick right beside my answer and make it as solution...thx..glad to got your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you please use this code for showing the menu as per your need ?

```
wp_nav_menu(
 array(
'menu_class'=>"nav navbar-nav navbar-right",
'menu_id'=>"",
 'container'=>"",
 'theme_location'=>"primary-menu",
 )
 );
```

Now it is the tested code and surely it will work.
Thanking you.

Answer (score 1):

I have got solution actually I was using primary menu, but when I created new menu from admin and use that menu then my classes automatically added in 'ul' tag, but thanks for your valuable answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not call these classes `nav navbar-nav navbar-right` in wp_nav_menu

try this code

```
<div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'menu' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => '', 'container' => false, 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'show_home' => '1')); ?>
</div>
```

`wp_nav_menu` generate menu in ul li, so when you call above classes the `wp_nav_menu` automatically assign div and classes

Hope this will help you

Comment: So remove all parameters except "'theme_location' => 'primary-menu'"

Comment: Dear I need something like this
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/incubation/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/incubation/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
    </ul>